# Hiding Navigation Bar in Android 5+

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, navigation-bar

Is it possible to hide the navigation bar in the footer along with the status bar at the top when I use apps by default in Android 5+ or do I require a fullscreen app to enable myself to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully from the settings, no.
I used to use an app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmd.hidesoftkeys (Whose Pro mod was epic) to hide the soft keys and swipe bottom of my screen to show them.

Comment: Are there any good options which don't require root (how do I sort root access, if I do need to go down that "route" :-)